# Python sockets [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-sockets

**This is not a duplicate.**

I have searched for literally hours to find the answer and no luck so I'm asking here.

I am currently building a chat server using python's socket module. When I run the server, after the client connects and the server says so, I receive an exception:

```
[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

I have built a drastically reduced server and it works where this server does not. This has confused me as it is doing the same thing nearly line for line.

[tcpServer.py](https://pastebin.com/wZRbrY1W)

[tcpClient.py](http://pastebin.com/BiUzNGq5)

Simplified:

[testServer.py](http://pastebin.com/uchBzyAy)

[testClient.py](https://pastebin.com/DnhGQH3y)

Comment: You should include code *in* your question, and also identify exactly where the problem occurred. See [ask]

Comment: That being said... What is wrong with this sequence?   `clientSocket.recv`, `clientSocket.shutdown`, `clientSocket.close`, `clientSocket.recv`  Perhaps `shutdown` and `close` are not correctly indented?

Comment: Here is some updated code: https://pastebin.com/QvC62Faq

Comment: It appears that I had copied some of the code. Probably while I was trying to debug this.

Comment: And again: https://pastebin.com/KiDVX9ey

Comment: I'm terrible at this: https://pastebin.com/wZRbrY1W

Answer (score 2):

let me clear a couple of things out for you:

- at server side: you **create** a socket, **bind** it, and **listen** for connections.
- at client side: you **create** a socket and then you try to **connect** to the server.

The server side in your case is fine, however, at the client side you need to remove this line:

```
s.bind(("127.0.0.1",port))
```

You would generally do something like this for example:

```
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = 1234
s.connect((ip, port))
s.send("hello".encode("utf-8"))
while True:
    s.send(input().encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Removed the `s.bind()` line in the client and still comes up with the same exception but thanks for that.

Comment: make sure that your indentations are correct, and you are **closing the sockets properly** as that's the reason why you're getting this error, I think you're trying to use the socket after calling shutdown or something similar. hope it works for you

Comment: After correcting my indentations I still have this error.